# Facebook photo picker

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I've seen in several apps a widget that let users pick a photo from their photo albums.
I was wondering if it's a build in facebook widget or it is self developed?
Does anyone know a free widget that I can use?

Comment: You have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a feature-rich one based on jQuery:

https://github.com/cshold/jQuery-Facebook-Photo-Selector

Comment: Thank you, this just saved me a lot of work building it myself.